# Cross-Correlation for non stationary data

Tags: time-series

I am using cross correlation to find the correlation between two time series data say X and Y. I have read this somewhere that :

" If X or Y contains auto-correlation or is not stationary about mean , the cross- correlation will not reflect the true relationship between X and Y.

What to do in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this post will be helpful to you http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68425/how-to-determine-correlation-between-stationary-and-non-stationary-time-series/68592#68592

Answer (score 2):

For non-stationary variables [we should always think in terms of cointegration](http://www.econ.ku.dk/metrics/Econometrics2_05_II/Slides/10_cointegration_2pp.pdf)

Comment: What do mean by this term ? can you explain it more?

Comment: The term is defined and explained well on page 5 of the slides that I linked to. You asked what to do and I mentioned the area of econometrics that you may need to study. There is a lot of research and expository material available on this topic, which you can summarize for yourself before asking further, more concrete questions.